# SQL oracle sort by date

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, date

I would like to show data created after 01.01.2014 - data created before should not be shown in the output.

I got this so far:

```
AND TO_CHAR(table1.datum,'IW') = 17 (number of the week - just a start from me)
AND TO_CHAR(table1.datum,'YYYY') = 2014 (shows only data from 2014)
```

Can you help me?

Comment: SELECT combined with WHERE.

Comment: Can you explain your background research for this? a simple google/bing should answer this - or a look at the dev documentation.

Comment: I got this so far:

AND TO_CHAR(table1.datum,'IW') = 17
AND TO_CHAR(table1.datum,'YYYY') = 2014

Comment: @piguy, good start. Move that comment to your question now! (To get better response!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to show data created after 01.01.2014 - data created before should not be shown in the output.

Then just put the **date condition** in the **filter predicate**.

```
WHERE table1.datum > TO_DATE('01-01-2014','DD-MM-YYYY')
```

**Note** that this will **not include the rows** which were **created on '01-01-2014'**, to include them as well you need **greater than or equal to**:

```
WHERE table1.datum >= TO_DATE('01-01-2014','DD-MM-YYYY')
```

For example,

```
SQL> WITH table1 AS(
  2  SELECT to_date('20-12-2013','DD-MM-YYYY') datum FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT to_date('01-04-2014','DD-MM-YYYY') datum FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT to_date('20-10-2015','DD-MM-YYYY') datum FROM dual
  5  )
  6  SELECT * FROM table1
  7  WHERE table1.datum >= TO_DATE('01-01-2014','DD-MM-YYYY')
  8  /

DATUM
---------
01-APR-14
20-OCT-15

SQL>
```

So, `'20-12-2013'` is filtered out and you have rows created only created after `'01.01.2014'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from table
Where the_date_field < to_date('01-01-2014','dd-mm-yyyy')
Order by ..... /* If needed */
```